# `Refactor` menu disappeared (Xcode 9.2, not _all_ projects)

Tags: xcode, xcode9.2

I've had problems before with the `Refactor…` menu getting [grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833848/xcode-9-beta-refactoring-rename-broken), but now it's disappeared entirely in one of my projects.

[image]
[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Quit Xcode + kill DerivedData + clean build + let indexing finish.
- Quit Xcode + remove com.apple.dt.* and com.apple.preferences.extensions.XcodeSourceEditor.plist

So far, nothing. Very much hoping this can be fixed without having to completely reinstall Xcode from scratch (again).

Comment: I restarted my laptop and that didn't seem to help either. Finally just put the prefs back and gave up…then discovered that the functionality _returned_ after I did some branch switching. No idea what fixed it in the end, but I'll just leave this here as a reference for anyone else having this issue.

Comment: I just had the same problem and after doing all the usual quit, clean, restart etc without any change I realised it was because I had Xcode in the source control comparison view, it seems refactoring is blocked in that state.